# ERROR EXPORTING DATA FROM MS EXCEL TO MS POWERPOINT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

what should I do with this code, it doesn't work. Especially I want to get the result of the copied data on the slide pasted on the the different position on each slide. Please help me how to modify the code below: Any help is greatly appreciated,
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... the code=>

```
    Sub CopyTOPowerPoint()

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shpArray As Variant
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim ppShape As Object
Dim ppShape1 As Object

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    
    'Clear the error
      Err.Clear

      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Maaf, file PowerPoint belum diaktifkan. Silahkan dibuka file nya y..,:)"
        Exit Sub
      End If

      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0
  
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate
    
'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
  
'List Slides PPT untuk di Paste
  MySlideArray = Array(1, 2)

    MyRangeArray = Array(Sheets("Sheets1").Range("A1:C9"), Sheets("Sheets1").Range("E1:G9"))
   
'Loop through Array data
  For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
    'Copy Excel Range
    On Error Resume Next
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy
     
    'Paste to PowerPoint and position
      On Error Resume Next
     
        Set shpArray = Array(ppShape, ppShape1)
        Set shpArray = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 'Excel 2007-2010
        With ppShape
            .Left = 86
            .Top = 535
        End With
        
        With ppShape1
            .Left = 100
            .Top = 100
        End With
      On Error GoTo 0
     
  Next x

'Transfer Complete
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: We can't help if we don't know the error message and what  line throws it.

Comment: It would help if you got rid of the last two `On Error Resume Next` which are presumably hiding the error.